# Angular 4 reactive form is not clearing the validations after resetting the form

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4.4.6 reactive form with Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.12 in my application. This is my component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-quick-file',
    templateUrl: './quick-file.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./quick-file.component.css']
})
export class QuickFileComponent implements OnInit {

    quickFileForm: FormGroup;


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initQuickFileForm();
    }

    private initQuickFileForm () {
        this.quickFileForm = new FormGroup({
            'fileOpenDate': new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
            'fileSubjectEn': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            'categoryId': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            'subCategoryId': new FormControl(null),
            'primaryClientId': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            'primaryConsultantId': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
        });
    }

    saveQuickFileForm() {
        console.log(this.quickFileForm);
        this.quickFileForm.reset();
    }

}
```

Here is my template,

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="quickFileForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuickFileForm()">
        <mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="openDatePicker" formControlName="fileOpenDate" placeholder="Choose Date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="openDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #openDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="fileSubjectEn" placeholder="Subject in English">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
            <mat-select formControlName="categoryId" placeholder="Choose category">
                <mat-option value="1">opt 1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2">opt 2</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="3">opt 3</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
            <mat-select formControlName="subCategoryId" placeholder="Choose subcategory">
                <mat-option value="1">opt 1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2">opt 2</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="3">opt 3</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
            <mat-select formControlName="primaryClientId" placeholder="Choose subcategory">
                <mat-option value="1">opt 1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2">opt 2</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="3">opt 3</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
            <mat-select formControlName="primaryConsultantId" placeholder="Choose subcategory">
                <mat-option value="1">opt 1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2">opt 2</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="3">opt 3</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>
```

Validation errors are showing even after I reset the form. I also tried the following methods.

```
this.quickFileForm.clearValidators();
this.quickFileForm.markAsPristine();
this.quickFileForm.markAsPristine();
```

What could be the error in my code and the possible solution? Thank you.

Comment: show your error log or it impossible to help you.

Comment: @RachChen Actually there is no error showing. Form values are clearing. But red color of the material input field (validation error) is not going.

Comment: Could you show your Demo on plunk?

Comment: Now formGroup.reset() is working without any bug in Angular 5. I have updated my Angular project to 5 and now it's working, no need to use localReference and resetForm() method.

Comment: resetForm() below may lead to unexpected behavior. You can define your own validations methods - see example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52676157/6332774

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be a known **[bug](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190)** when having a button of type `submit`. There are some work-arounds presented in that issue, of which I would use the `ngForm` directive:

```
<form [formGroup]="quickFileForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuickFileForm()" #f="ngForm">
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('f') myForm;

saveQuickFileForm() {
  this.myForm.resetForm();
}
```

This seems to work fine! **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3klfz7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: You are very welcome :) Have a nice day and happy coding! :)

Comment: Hi, i have same problem with reset..but this does not seem to work for me :(

Comment: Sorry my bad..it works dude thanks for this! just forget to empty cache on refresh..:)

Answer (score 2):

@AJT_82, we've modified a bit of your code dude.

```
<form [formGroup]="quickFileForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuickFileForm(f)" #f="ngForm">

saveQuickFileForm(form) {
  console.log(this.quickFileForm);
  form.resetForm();
}
```

Eliminated @ViewChild, Seems to work also..BTW Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case nothing visually works for you, I did it via jquery:

```
$("#form .form-control").each((idx, ctrl)=>{$(ctrl).removeClass("is-invalid")});
```