# Angular2 reset form and mark as untouched

Tags: angular

How can I reset a form and mark as untouched, clean etc after I submit because I stay on the page and user can resubmit

```
    this.myForm.reset()
    this.myForm.markAsPristine()
    this.myForm.controls['options_name'].markAsUntouched()
```

When I reset I get a validation error with red underline.  The form does reset just I get a validation error that looks ugly.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="options_name" style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;width: 110px;">
    <md-error *ngIf="myForm.controls['options_name'].hasError('required')">
          <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: You have a typo... should be `this.myForm.controls['options_name'].markAsUntouched()`

Comment: still not working I updated the post

Comment: There's some kind of 'bug' with material, check out my answer here if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47068454/6294072

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help someone else.

I am sure all experienced developers would find a workaround for this. I thought below would help some beginners though.

You can define your own untouched variable as an alternative as follows:

```
<div [hidden]="q_text.valid || q_text.pristine || isQTextUnTouched" class="warning">
```

Then in your input add       (ngModelChange)="onQTextChanged()"     as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="q_text" autocomplete="off" size="40" required 
        [(ngModel)]="model.q_text" (ngModelChange)="onQTextChanged()" 
        name="q_text" #q_text="ngModel">
```

Then add to onQTextChanged() following:

```
onQTextChanged() {
    this.isQTextUnTouched = false;
  }
```

Then every time you reset the form set     this.isQTextUnTouched = true;

That is it.

In my app a component (LoopQuestions) loops questions using form defined in another component (QuestionForm). And I do reset this.isQTextUnTouched to true in the constructor where RxJS subscription is used.

For this I use example from [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service), but instead of mission the missioncontrol.component.ts (in my case LoopQuestions) sends a new instance of QuestionModel to astronaut.component.ts (in my case QuestionForm). Instead of mission acceptance confirmation in astronaut.component.ts  QuestionForm confirms that form has been submitted. And then LoopQuestions immediately sends a new instance of QuestionModel again.

constructor of LoopQuestions:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private newPollService: NewPollService) {
    newPollService.aQuestionCompleted$.subscribe(
      () => {
        this.q_number++;
        if (this.q_number > this.q_qnty) { this.router.navigate(['/home']); }
        this.goToNextQuestion();
      });
  }

  goToNextQuestion() {
    const nextQuestion = new QuestionModel( ... your default values ... );
    this.newPollService.announceQuestionStart(nextQuestion);
  }
```

constructor of QuestionForm:

```
  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private newPollService: NewPollService
    ) {
    this.subscription = newPollService.questionLoopStarted$.subscribe(
      nextQuestion => {
        this.isQTextUnTouched = true;
        this.model = nextQuestion;
      }
    );
  }
```

LoopQuestion's html:

```
<div>
    <h4>New question - question # {{q_number}}:</h4>

  <app-question-form></app-question-form>

</div>
```

Note: I did not add any kind of form.reset() because it led to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular [setValue Or patchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for reactive forms.