# required validator still active after using clearValidators()

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a list of rows, each with some selects, inputs, and a checkbox that looks like this

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="chargeApply[charge]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            (change)="setChargeValidators(charge, $event.checked)"></mat-checkbox>
```

The intent is for setChargeValidators to add/remove validators for the row that was selected/unselected, this is the function (there's a lot of extra things that work fine that I'm not explaining about the function, the important part is clearing the validators when selected is false, and CELL_VALIDATION is an array containing Validators.required):

```
setChargeValidators(charge: string, selected: boolean) {
if (selected) {
  this.chargesSelected = true;
  this.chargesForm.controls[charge + '20'].setValidators(CELL_VALIDATION);
  this.chargesForm.controls[charge + '40'].setValidators(CELL_VALIDATION);
  this.chargesForm.controls[charge + '40hc'].setValidators(CELL_VALIDATION);
  this.chargesForm.controls[charge + 'Currency'].setValidators(Validators.required);
  this.chargesForm.controls[charge + 'Unit'].setValidators(Validators.required);
} else {
  const controlNames = ['20', '40', '40hc', 'Currency', 'Unit'];
  for (let name of controlNames) {
    if (name !== 'Currency' ) {
      this.chargesForm.controls[charge + name].reset();
    }
    this.chargesForm.controls[charge + name].clearValidators();
  }

  for (let chargeName in this.chargeApply) {
    if (this.chargeApply[chargeName]) {
      return;
    }
  }
  this.chargesSelected = false;
}

this.updateForm(charge);}
```

UpdateForm looks like this

```
updateForm(charge) {
const controlNames = ['20', '40', '40hc', 'Currency', 'Unit'];
for (let name of controlNames) {
  this.chargesForm.controls[charge + name].updateValueAndValidity();
  // debugger
}
```

}

However, when I unselect a row, all FormControls of that row have

> error: {required: true}

It seems that all validators are clearing, except for Validators.required. I've tried doing

> this.chargesForm.controls[charge + name].clearAsyncValidators();

In adition to clearValidators(), with no effect (which makes sense since I'm not setting any async validation). I've also tried [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067060/angular-4-reactive-form-is-not-clearing-the-validations-after-resetting-the-form/47068454#47068454) with no luck.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A side comment, I wouldn't recommend you to use ngModel and reactive forms together!  https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Comment: You're correct to point that out, but that binding is working as intended for now.